# How to make a loading progress bar in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I've seen this page from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp) for progress bars. I am new to bootstrap and for web programming. It is possible to make it 100% in just 5 seconds?. Like a loading progress bar.

What is a correct way to do it?

Comment: Here's a similar question on bootstrap progress bar..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182058/dynamically-change-bootstrap-progress-bar-value-when-checkboxes-checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using twitter bootstrap and jQuery.

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/f6hLt9ak/2/

I have used window.setInterval to set the value for progress-bar every half second. Once the progress bar reaches 100%, I am resetting the value back to 0.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                        0%
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
var progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
var percentVal = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
    percentVal += 10;
    progressBar.css("width", percentVal+ '%').attr("aria-valuenow", percentVal+ '%').text(percentVal+ '%'); 

    if (percentVal == 100)
    {
        percentVal = 0;      
    }

}, 500);
```

I hope this code sample will give you an idea on how to proceed at your end.

Comment: Can this be possible if the progress bar is 100% it will stop and do something...

Comment: Yes, it will possible. Once the progress bar reaches 100% (you can detect that using percentVal variable value), stop the setInterval using clearInterval function and then perform the next desired action. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are confused to add a progress bar.Try automated progress bar

[Pace.Js](https://codebyzach.github.io/pace/)

Pace is really simple to integrate with web pages.

Add/Copy Stylesheet on your webpage

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/black/pace-theme-barber-shop.css">
```

And add JS file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.js"></script>
```

---

Sit back Rest of the things Pace will do

Comment: 404, site doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Updated the broken link