# Changing the value of a bootstrap component dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the value within a bootstrap component that will change on a button click event

Here is my component.  It is a small bar that fills to a certain percentage depending on what value has been entered in through the markup code

```
<div class="progress">
 <div id="theprogressbar" class ="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
style="width: 95%">
  <span class="sr-only">95% Complete</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**style="width: 95%"** is what is needed to be changed in order to change the percentage that the bar is filled with.  Here is an example of what the bootstrap component looks like
[image]
How would I go about changing the percentage value within a button click event? thanks in advance and sorry if I seem vague! c# is the coding language I am using and this is taking place on a web form

UPDATE: JQUERY CODE

```
<script>


$('#btnSave').click(function () {
    $.ajax({

    url: 'http://localhost:61417/ProjectMainMenu/GetProgress',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response){
        var progressValue=response.d;
        $('#theprogressbar').attr('aria-valuenow', progressValue).css('width',progressValue);
        $("#progressValue").text(progressValue);
    }
        });

     </script>
```

C# CODE

```
      [WebMethod]
public static double GetProgress()
{
     double progress=0;
     //Your Business Logic
     progress=56;
     return progress;
}
```

BUTTON MARKUP CODE

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" width =" 250px" runat="server" Text="View"  class="btn btn-info" />
```

Comment: It's actually very vague... You will probably have to write some javascript code to update this.

Comment: sorry ill try update it to make it more understandable

Comment: I also think you'll end up using Javascript for this. Don't forget to update the aria-valuenow property as well to maintain accessibility.

Comment: Refer it from the [so question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182058/dynamically-change-bootstrap-progress-bar-value-when-checkboxes-checked). Hopefully,It would be solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use WebMethod attribute which work as a web service method.

**HTML & Jquery**

```
<div class="progress">
     <div id="theprogressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 95%">
     <span class="sr-only"><span id="progressValue">95</span>% Complete</span>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
```

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:56894/Progress.aspx/GetProgress',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(response){
                var progressValue=response.d;
                $('#theprogressbar').attr('aria-valuenow', progressValue).css('width',progressValue);
                $("#progressValue").text(progressValue);
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

**ASP.NET Web Form**

```
[WebMethod]
public static double GetProgress()
{
     double progress=0;
     //Your Business Logic
     progress=56;
     return progress;
}
```

**Javascript**

Comment: The question asked refers to webforms, so I an API controller would not work in this instance

Comment: tried it, its not working and I have changed the values to match my own.  The button is called btnSave and I have changed the url to match my url.  any ideas?

Comment: the btn click event is not firing either

Comment: @GenericOverweightProgrammer please check your jquery working or not, you can just simply call alert(0); under the click event.

Comment: As mentioned by @peeebeee the "Value now" needs to be updated, anyway to implement that

Comment: alert(0) is not calling

Comment: that means your jquery is not calling, could you please update your question with jquery code

Comment: let me try your code with a new project in my side.